# d3fc with NextJS - Error: d3fc-element depends on Custom Elements (v1). Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, next.js, d3fc

How to properly use d3fc package with NextJS app. I get error when i just imported package. This solution doesn't help me
https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc/issues/1207

Thanks

```
"use client"
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as fc from 'd3fc'
```

> ⨯ node_modules/d3fc/build/d3fc.js (10226:12) @ eval  ⨯ Error:
> d3fc-element depends on Custom Elements (v1). Make sure that you load
> a polyfill in older browsers. See README.

my packages versions are:

```
"d3": "^7.8.5",
"d3fc": "^15.2.6",
"next": "^14.0.4",
```

**UPD:**
When i installed ***ungap/custom-elements*** package i get another error

> ⨯ node_modules/@ungap/custom-elements/index.js (179:16) @ self  ⨯
> ReferenceError: self is not defined